The equivalence of stochastic quantization and path integral quantization
I am looking for a reference in which the equivalence of stochastic quantization and
path integral quantization has been shown. It would be great if I can see such a relation for a Euclidean quantum field theory like $\phi^4$ model.

I am aware of this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0312315. I wonder if there is another paper/book.

Some older sources than https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0312315 that prove the equivalence between stochastic quantisation and regular QFT (Euclidean path integrals) include:

Equivalence of stochastic and canonical quantization in perturbation theory (1983).
Equivalence of stochastic quantization and the Faddeev-Popov Ansatz (1981).


I found the equivalence of stochastic quantization and path integral quantization for the $\phi^4$ model using the Langevin dynamics in Sec.~3.3.2 of this paper.
